# How to draw a 1 pixel-wide smooth border on a UIView, with a cornerRadius?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

Here is the code I use to setup the border of my UIView:

```
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height/2;
self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

The horizontal part is correct, but is there a way of getting the curved parts "smoother" whilst keeping a 1 pixel line width on retina devices? It looks very aliased right now.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the value of cornerRadius, the rendering system draws differently if it is has decimal points or not

Answer (score 1):

You should change `self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;` to `self.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;`